# Why is libxml not storing html in my htmlDocPtr?

Tags: c++, libxml2

I am working on a piece of software that uses libxml to store xml on webpages in an xmlDocPtr. I need to expand this functionality to do the same for html.

The original code:

```
xmlDocPtr doc = xmlParseEntity(filename.c_str());
```

Where filename = 10.1.1.135/poll_data.xml and everything works just fine

Now, I have html filename = 10.1.1.165/index.htm and would like to store this as well. I have tried using htmlParseDoc with no success.

```
htmlDocPtr doc = htmlParseFile(filename.c_str(), "windows-1252");
```

The resulting doc object is not null but it does not contain the contents of the index.html

Netbeans spits out:

*http://10.1.1.165/index.htm:1: HTML parser error : Document is empty*

Any suggestions?

Comment: That looks like a URL, not a file.  Actually download the file first, then see if it can be parsed.

Comment: If I download it I can parse it. However, it is important that I can retrieve the html from a webpage and not on my local system. I've tried looking through their documentation but it isn't very clear to me.

Comment: So it is actually the 10.1.1.135 machine that is the oddball, it lets you access a file without anything resembling a share name.  Hard to guess how that works, talk to IT staff about giving the 10.1.1.165 machine the same capability.

Comment: Typos are one of the first things I would look at. Have you tried, for example, entering `10.1.1.165/index.htm` in a web browser to make sure the URL is correct?

Comment: That is a valid web address. 10.1.1.165 is the actual page but index.htm is how I access the html

Comment: @B.Hoeper Technically, the URL `10.1.1.165` names a computer, not a page. It probably works to get the page you want because many web servers are configured to silently redirect such requests to `index.htm` in the server's root. In that case, `10.1.1.165/index.htm` should yield the same page. So we come back to the test: have you tried entering `10.1.1.165/index.htm` in your browser? (This would verify that the server believes the page name is `index.htm` rather than, for example, `index.html`. Quick and easy for someone on your private network.)

Comment: @JaMiT If I navigate to 10.1.1.165/index.htm it loads my desired page.